# How to extract and combine rows from data frames inside a list in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset, purrr

My real data is allocated in a big list of 95 data frames. Each data frame has thousands of rows and 8 columns. In order to be simpler and clearer, I created these analogous objects with dummy data.

```
state <- c("MG", "SP", "PR")
individual <- c("ind1", "ind2", "ind3")
sample <- c("a", "b", "c")

df1 <- data.frame(var1, state, individual, sample)
df2 <- data.frame(var1, state, individual, sample)
df3 <- data.frame(var1, state, individual, sample)

df_total <- list(df1, df2, df3)

names(df_total) <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")

df_total

#> df_total
#$df1
#        var1 state individual sample
#1  0.3898432    MG       ind1      a
#2 -0.6212406    SP       ind2      b
#3 -2.2146999    PR       ind3      c
#
#$df2
#        var1 state individual sample
#1  0.3898432    MG       ind1      a
#2 -0.6212406    SP       ind2      b
#3 -2.2146999    PR       ind3      c
#
#$df3
#        var1 state individual sample
#1  0.3898432    MG       ind1      a
#2 -0.6212406    SP       ind2      b
#3 -2.2146999    PR       ind3      c
```

All data frames are identical in structure, containing information about the same individuals in different contexts.

My goal is to be able to extract and combine rows from all the data frames into new data frames, keeping the column titles.

**More precisely, I want to generate a data frame with all rows that mention “ind1” on the `individual` column, one with all rows that mention “ind2” and so on. As I have 95 different individuals in my real data, I would like a solution that loops and create a data frame for each different name contained in that column without calling them individually.**

It has been a few days since I’m trying this using dplyr and purrr, but failing miserably…

Any suggestions for a beginner?

Comment: From reading your description, I have some confusion.  Do you want to create a new `list` based on the 'indvidual' column

Answer (score 1):

We can use `bind_rows` with `.id` to create an identifier column with the `names` of the `list` and then `group_split` with the 'individual' column

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df_total, .id = 'grp')%>% 
        group_split(individual)
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#   var1 state individual sample grp  
#  <dbl> <fct> <fct>      <fct>  <chr>
#1 0.390 MG    ind1       a      df1  
#2 0.390 MG    ind1       a      df2  
#3 0.390 MG    ind1       a      df3  

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#    var1 state individual sample grp  
#   <dbl> <fct> <fct>      <fct>  <chr>
#1 -0.621 SP    ind2       b      df1  
#2 -0.621 SP    ind2       b      df2  
#3 -0.621 SP    ind2       b      df3  

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#   var1 state individual sample grp  
#  <dbl> <fct> <fct>      <fct>  <chr>
#1 -2.21 PR    ind3       c      df1  
#2 -2.21 PR    ind3       c      df2  
#3 -2.21 PR    ind3       c      df3
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly, @akrun, thanks a lot!
Is there a way to keep the common section of the original df names as the name of the new df?

The names will be present in the new variable 'grp'.

Comment: @WagnerNogueira i didn't get your questiion.  Do you need only `df` instead of `df1`, `df2` etc>

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(paste0("ind", 1:95), function(y){
  do.call('rbind', lapply(df_total, function(x) x[individual == y, ]))
} )
```

or

```
apply(do.call('rbind', lapply(df_total, function(x) split(x, x$individual))), 2, function(y) do.call('rbind', y))
# $ind1
#          var1 state individual sample
# df1 0.3898432    MG       ind1      a
# df2 0.3898432    MG       ind1      a
# df3 0.3898432    MG       ind1      a
# 
# $ind2
#           var1 state individual sample
# df1 -0.6212406    SP       ind2      b
# df2 -0.6212406    SP       ind2      b
# df3 -0.6212406    SP       ind2      b
# 
# $ind3
#        var1 state individual sample
# df1 -2.2147    PR       ind3      c
# df2 -2.2147    PR       ind3      c
# df3 -2.2147    PR       ind3      c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution

```
res <- split(u<-do.call(rbind,df_total),u$individual)
```

such that

```
> res
$ind1
           var1 state individual sample
df1.1 0.3898432    MG       ind1      a
df2.1 0.3898432    MG       ind1      a
df3.1 0.3898432    MG       ind1      a

$ind2
            var1 state individual sample
df1.2 -0.6212406    SP       ind2      b
df2.2 -0.6212406    SP       ind2      b
df3.2 -0.6212406    SP       ind2      b

$ind3
         var1 state individual sample
df1.3 -2.2147    PR       ind3      c
df2.3 -2.2147    PR       ind3      c
df3.3 -2.2147    PR       ind3      c
```